# Prove $\cos x= 2 \cos^2{\frac{x}{2}}-1=1-2\sin^2{\frac{x}{2}}$

Tags: trigonometry

How would I prove the following trig identity?

$$\cos x= 2 \cos^2{\frac{x}{2}}-1=1-2\sin^2{\frac{x}{2}}$$

I am not sure where to begin any help would be useful.

Comment: Hint: $\cos x = \cos \left(\frac x2 + \frac x2\right)$ ... and you now a formula for $\cos(a+b)$, don't you?

Comment: Another hint: $\cos(x/2) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{ix/2}+e^{-ix/2})$.

Comment: I have never seen the second one marlu commented but I know cos(a+b) is cosAcosB-cosAsinB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure you know the formula $\cos(a+b) = \cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b$. Let $a=b = \frac{x}{2}$, which gives $\cos x = (\cos \frac{x}{2})^2 - (\sin \frac{x}{2})^2$. Since $(\cos \frac{x}{2})^2 + (\sin \frac{x}{2})^2 = 1$, this gives $\cos x = (\cos \frac{x}{2})^2 + (\cos \frac{x}{2})^2 -1$, which is your formula above.

The other follows a similar approach, except you replace the $(\cos \frac{x}{2})^2$ term instead of the $(\sin \frac{x}{2})^2$ term.

Here is the second part explicitly:

We already have $\cos x = (\cos \frac{x}{2})^2 - (\sin \frac{x}{2})^2$. Since $(\cos \frac{x}{2})^2 + (\sin \frac{x}{2})^2 = 1$, this gives $(\cos \frac{x}{2})^2 = 1-(\sin \frac{x}{2})^2$. Substituting gives $\cos x = 1-(\sin \frac{x}{2})^2 - (\sin \frac{x}{2})^2 = 1-2 (\sin \frac{x}{2})^2$.

Comment: For my second one I have sin(x/2)cos(x/2)+cos(x/2)sin(x/2) but how would I proceed do I need to add them or something?

Comment: Just replace $(\cos \frac{x}{2})^2$ by $1-(\sin \frac{x}{2})^2$.

Comment: Your question doesn't have a $\sin x$ expansion?

Comment: Now I have sin(x/2)(1-sin(x/2)+(1-sinx/2)sin(x/2)

Comment: Still I am unsure what to....

Comment: Fernando, I don't know what you are doing. The formula above gives $\cos x = (\cos \frac{x}{2})^2 - (\sin \frac{x}{2})^2$. Just replace the $(\cos \frac{x}{2})^2$ by $1-(\sin \frac{x}{2})^2$ and simplify slightly. There's nothing more to it.

Comment: Sorry I meant on the second part of the question when cosx=1-2sin^2(x/2) dont I have to sin(a+b) for that part?

Comment: I must be missing something?

Comment: hmm actually never mind I thought you also had to prove the right most part of the identity to the the other 2 parts.

Comment: I added the second part to the answer above.

Comment: Thanks I see now.What confuses me are all those substitutions of the identities.

Comment: I understand. Do them one at a time. I make mistakes all the time; I often use a symbolic manipulation system to check my calculations (wxmaxima).

Answer (score 0):

Paint is here to help you! Just stare at the image below long enough and realize everything is ok. After, use Pythagoras' theorem:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(1 + \cos(x))^2 + \sin^2(x) \\ = (2\cos(x/2))^2 \\ = 1 + 2\cos(x) + (\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x))\\ = 2 + 2\cos(x) \\ = 4\cos^2(x/2).
\end{aligned}$$

Now, you can write

$$1+\cos(x) = 2\cos^2(x/2)\\\\ \Longrightarrow \cos(x) = 2\cos^2(x/2) - 1.$$

[image: Paint]